# Filter xml column in T-SQL from WhoIsActive

Tags: sql-server

Simple question, how do I query an XML column containing values like this:

```
<?query --
select statistic_name_id, convert(varchar(1024), statistic_name), datasource_id, statistic_class_id, datatype_guide, derived, using_wide_string from spotlight_stat_names
--?>
```

I use WhoIsActive from Adam Mechanic with a destination table. I got a lot of rows and I want to filter out some. Please help.

Comment: the sp WhoIsActive output a column of type xml. I also dont understands this of xml format

Comment: Formatted:  [sql_text] [xml] NULL
Non-Formatted: [sql_text] [nvarchar](max) NULL

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from WhoIsActivetable
where cast(sql_text as varchar(max)) like '%statistic_name_id%'
```

---

```
select sql_text, cast(sql_text as varchar(max))  from WhoIsActivetable
```